# CSS: How to allign properly li elements using li before dash

Tags: css

I have created a simple `ul` using a dash to display the `li` elements.

[Here is the example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/web_garaux/814v0eun/2/):

The `li` are not aligned properly:

**Current li**

–Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque cursus, risus eu fringilla **blandit**, ante dolor malesuada massa, in rhoncus dui justo sed risus
**blandit** should be alligned to Lorem.

Here is the css code I am using

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

li {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 0.1em;
  text-indent: -.5em;
}

li:before {
  content: "– ";
  color: #333;
}
```

Comment: this is not a solution, is a hotfix: you can use `margin-left: -.2em;` in the :before element. Change the value to adapt if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use padding on the li and absolute positioning for the dash (and remove the text indent):

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

li {
  padding-left: 1.2em;    /* amount of space for the dash */
  padding-bottom: 0.1em;
  position: relative;
}

li:before {
  content: "–";
  color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque cursus, risus eu fringilla blandit, ante dolor malesuada massa, in rhoncus dui justo sed risus</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque cursus, risus eu fringilla blandit, ante dolor malesuada massa, in rhoncus dui justo sed risus</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque cursus, risus eu fringilla blandit, ante dolor malesuada massa, in rhoncus dui justo sed risus</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque cursus, risus eu fringilla blandit, ante dolor malesuada massa, in rhoncus dui justo sed risus</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make li **padding-left = text-indent**.

For example:

```
{
   padding-left: .5em; 
   padding-bottom: 0.1em;
   text-indent: -.5em;
}
```

or make them 10px as u want

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:0;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  
   
}

  li { 
    padding-left: 10px; 
    padding-bottom: 0.1em;
    text-indent: -10px;
}

  li:before {
    content: "– ";
    color: #333; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque cursus, risus eu fringilla blandit, ante dolor malesuada massa, in rhoncus dui justo sed risus</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque cursus, risus eu fringilla blandit, ante dolor malesuada massa, in rhoncus dui justo sed risus</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque cursus, risus eu fringilla blandit, ante dolor malesuada massa, in rhoncus dui justo sed risus</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque cursus, risus eu fringilla blandit, ante dolor malesuada massa, in rhoncus dui justo sed risus</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply `position: absolute` to `li::before` will do the trick

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  
   
}

  li { 
    padding-left: 10px;
    
    padding-bottom: 0.1em;
    /*text-indent: -.5em;*/
  
}

  li:before {
    content: "– ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    color: #333; 
 
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque cursus, risus eu fringilla blandit, ante dolor malesuada massa, in rhoncus dui justo sed risus</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque cursus, risus eu fringilla blandit, ante dolor malesuada massa, in rhoncus dui justo sed risus</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque cursus, risus eu fringilla blandit, ante dolor malesuada massa, in rhoncus dui justo sed risus</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque cursus, risus eu fringilla blandit, ante dolor malesuada massa, in rhoncus dui justo sed risus</li>
</ul>
```